# Is there a way alter the color lines on D3.js line chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

fairly new to D3.js but keen to update the color scheme of my currently working version, the color: `steelblue` is used in the `.css` files but seems to be getting overridden from somewhere else, any idea how to best go about this? (as you can see i've tried updating to pink)

```
.chart-wrapper .line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: pink;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}
```

```
  // Render the chart
  chartObj.render = function () {
    //Create SVG element
    chartObj.svg = chartObj.chartDiv
      .append('svg')
      .attr('class', 'chart-area')
      .attr(
        'width',
        chartObj.width + (chartObj.margin.left + chartObj.margin.right)
      )
      .attr(
        'height',
        chartObj.height + (chartObj.margin.top + chartObj.margin.bottom)
      )
      .append('g')
      .attr(
        'transform',
        'translate(' + chartObj.margin.left + ',' + chartObj.margin.top + ')'
      );
    // Draw Lines
    for (var y in yObjs) {
      yObjs[y].path = chartObj.svg
        .append('path')
        .datum(chartObj.data)
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .attr('d', yObjs[y].line)
        .style('stroke', color(y))
        .attr('data-series', y)
        .on('mouseover', function () {
          focus.style('display', null);
        })
        .on('mouseout', function () {
          focus.transition().delay(700).style('display', 'none');
        })
        .on('mousemove', mousemove);
    }
  return chartObj;
}
```

Comment: The .style() call on chartObj.svg applies color(y) to the stroke property. Where is the color function defined? That will define a inline style setting for the line.

Comment: So - as John pointed out - you can also remove the line `.style('stroke', color(y))` and then the css style should be applied

Comment: sorry I couldn't add more of my JS code - I can update `.style('stroke', 'pink')` (the class `pink` just updates the stroke color, but it impacts both lines, do you know how I can differentiate between them? 

I've linked a fiddle with my JS included (sorry the chart won't work as I cant add an CSV) appreciate the help!

https://jsfiddle.net/simoncunningham/bzm5ftL0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are basing your code on this example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/asielen/44ffca2877d0132572cb) which is quite an in-depth place to start if you are new to d3.

I have modified the code to utilize the colour specified in the configuration object which appears to have been proposed but not implemented by the author of the example.

Previously the colours were generated according to the built-in `d3.scale.category10` colours but this has been removed.

This example code also uses d3 version 3 which probably means it is not a great starting point as the newer versions provide many API improvements. If you are interested in learning more about d3 colour schemes then please see [this article here](https://observablehq.com/@d3/color-schemes)

```js
function makeLineChart(dataset, xName, yObjs, axisLables) {
    var chartObj = {};
    var color = d3.scale.category10();
    chartObj.xAxisLable = axisLables.xAxis;
    chartObj.yAxisLable = axisLables.yAxis;
    /*
     yObjsects format:
     {y1:{column:'',name:'name',color:'color'},y2}
     */

    chartObj.data = dataset;
    chartObj.margin = {top: 15, right: 60, bottom: 30, left: 50};
    chartObj.width = 650 - chartObj.margin.left - chartObj.margin.right;
    chartObj.height = 480 - chartObj.margin.top - chartObj.margin.bottom;

// So we can pass the x and y as strings when creating the function
    chartObj.xFunct = function(d){return d[xName]};

// For each yObjs argument, create a yFunction
    function getYFn(column) {
        return function (d) {
            return d[column];
        };
    }

// Object instead of array
    chartObj.yFuncts = [];
    for (var y  in yObjs) {
        yObjs[y].name = y;
        yObjs[y].yFunct = getYFn(yObjs[y].column); //Need this  list for the ymax function
        chartObj.yFuncts.push(yObjs[y].yFunct);
        yObjs[y].color = d3.rgb(yObjs[y].color);
    }

//Formatter functions for the axes
    chartObj.formatAsNumber = d3.format(".0f");
    chartObj.formatAsDecimal = d3.format(".2f");
    chartObj.formatAsCurrency = d3.format("$.2f");
    chartObj.formatAsFloat = function (d) {
        if (d % 1 !== 0) {
            return d3.format(".2f")(d);
        } else {
            return d3.format(".0f")(d);
        }
        
    };

    chartObj.xFormatter = chartObj.formatAsNumber;
    chartObj.yFormatter = chartObj.formatAsFloat;

    chartObj.bisectYear = d3.bisector(chartObj.xFunct).left; //< Can be overridden in definition

//Create scale functions
    chartObj.xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, chartObj.width]).domain(d3.extent(chartObj.data, chartObj.xFunct)); //< Can be overridden in definition

// Get the max of every yFunct
    chartObj.max = function (fn) {
        return d3.max(chartObj.data, fn);
    };
    chartObj.yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([chartObj.height, 0]).domain([0, d3.max(chartObj.yFuncts.map(chartObj.max))]);

    chartObj.formatAsYear = d3.format("");

//Create axis
    chartObj.xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(chartObj.xScale).orient("bottom").tickFormat(chartObj.xFormatter); //< Can be overridden in definition

    chartObj.yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(chartObj.yScale).orient("left").tickFormat(chartObj.yFormatter); //< Can be overridden in definition


// Build line building functions
    function getYScaleFn(yObj) {
        return function (d) {
            return chartObj.yScale(yObjs[yObj].yFunct(d));
        };
    }
    for (var yObj in yObjs) {
        yObjs[yObj].line = d3.svg.line().interpolate("cardinal").x(function (d) {
            return chartObj.xScale(chartObj.xFunct(d));
        }).y(getYScaleFn(yObj));
    }
    

    chartObj.svg;

// Change chart size according to window size
    chartObj.update_svg_size = function () {
        chartObj.width = parseInt(chartObj.chartDiv.style("width"), 10) - (chartObj.margin.left + chartObj.margin.right);

        chartObj.height = parseInt(chartObj.chartDiv.style("height"), 10) - (chartObj.margin.top + chartObj.margin.bottom);

        /* Update the range of the scale with new width/height */
        chartObj.xScale.range([0, chartObj.width]);
        chartObj.yScale.range([chartObj.height, 0]);

        if (!chartObj.svg) {return false;}

        /* Else Update the axis with the new scale */
        chartObj.svg.select('.x.axis').attr("transform", "translate(0," + chartObj.height + ")").call(chartObj.xAxis);
        chartObj.svg.select('.x.axis .label').attr("x", chartObj.width / 2);

        chartObj.svg.select('.y.axis').call(chartObj.yAxis);
        chartObj.svg.select('.y.axis .label').attr("x", -chartObj.height / 2);

        /* Force D3 to recalculate and update the line */
        for (var y  in yObjs) {
            yObjs[y].path.attr("d", yObjs[y].line);
        }
        

        d3.selectAll(".focus.line").attr("y2", chartObj.height);

        chartObj.chartDiv.select('svg').attr("width", chartObj.width + (chartObj.margin.left + chartObj.margin.right)).attr("height", chartObj.height + (chartObj.margin.top + chartObj.margin.bottom));

        chartObj.svg.select(".overlay").attr("width", chartObj.width).attr("height", chartObj.height);
        return chartObj;
    };

    chartObj.bind = function (selector) {
        chartObj.mainDiv = d3.select(selector);
        // Add all the divs to make it centered and responsive
        chartObj.mainDiv.append("div").attr("class", "inner-wrapper").append("div").attr("class", "outer-box").append("div").attr("class", "inner-box");
        chartSelector = selector + " .inner-box";
        chartObj.chartDiv = d3.select(chartSelector);
        d3.select(window).on('resize.' + chartSelector, chartObj.update_svg_size);
        chartObj.update_svg_size();
        return chartObj;
    };

// Render the chart
    chartObj.render = function () {
        //Create SVG element
        chartObj.svg = chartObj.chartDiv.append("svg").attr("class", "chart-area").attr("width", chartObj.width + (chartObj.margin.left + chartObj.margin.right)).attr("height", chartObj.height + (chartObj.margin.top + chartObj.margin.bottom)).append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + chartObj.margin.left + "," + chartObj.margin.top + ")");

        // Draw Lines
        for (var y  in yObjs) {
            yObjs[y].path = chartObj.svg.append("path").datum(chartObj.data).attr("class", "line").attr("d", yObjs[y].line).style("stroke", yObjs[y].color).attr("data-series", y).on("mouseover", function () {
                focus.style("display", null);
            }).on("mouseout", function () {
                focus.transition().delay(700).style("display", "none");
            }).on("mousemove", mousemove);
        }
        

        // Draw Axis
        chartObj.svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + chartObj.height + ")").call(chartObj.xAxis).append("text").attr("class", "label").attr("x", chartObj.width / 2).attr("y", 30).style("text-anchor", "middle").text(chartObj.xAxisLable);

        chartObj.svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(chartObj.yAxis).append("text").attr("class", "label").attr("transform", "rotate(-90)").attr("y", -42).attr("x", -chartObj.height / 2).attr("dy", ".71em").style("text-anchor", "middle").text(chartObj.yAxisLable);

        //Draw tooltips
        var focus = chartObj.svg.append("g").attr("class", "focus").style("display", "none");

        for (var y  in yObjs) {
            yObjs[y].tooltip = focus.append("g");
            yObjs[y].tooltip.append("circle").attr("r", 5);
            yObjs[y].tooltip.append("rect").attr("x", 8).attr("y","-5").attr("width",22).attr("height",'0.75em');
            yObjs[y].tooltip.append("text").attr("x", 9).attr("dy", ".35em");
        }

        // Year label
        focus.append("text").attr("class", "focus year").attr("x", 9).attr("y", 7);
        // Focus line
        focus.append("line").attr("class", "focus line").attr("y1", 0).attr("y2", chartObj.height);

        //Draw legend
        var legend = chartObj.mainDiv.append('div').attr("class", "legend");
        for (var y  in yObjs) {
            series = legend.append('div');
            series.append('div').attr("class", "series-marker").style("background-color", yObjs[y].color);
            series.append('p').text(y);
            yObjs[y].legend = series;
        }

        // Overlay to capture hover
        chartObj.svg.append("rect").attr("class", "overlay").attr("width", chartObj.width).attr("height", chartObj.height).on("mouseover", function () {
            focus.style("display", null);
        }).on("mouseout", function () {
            focus.style("display", "none");
        }).on("mousemove", mousemove);

        return chartObj;
        function mousemove() {
            var x0 = chartObj.xScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]), i = chartObj.bisectYear(dataset, x0, 1), d0 = chartObj.data[i - 1], d1 = chartObj.data[i];
            try {
                var d = x0 - chartObj.xFunct(d0) > chartObj.xFunct(d1) - x0 ? d1 : d0;
            } catch (e) { return;}
            minY = chartObj.height;
            for (var y  in yObjs) {
                yObjs[y].tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + chartObj.xScale(chartObj.xFunct(d)) + "," + chartObj.yScale(yObjs[y].yFunct(d)) + ")");
                yObjs[y].tooltip.select("text").text(chartObj.yFormatter(yObjs[y].yFunct(d)));
                minY = Math.min(minY, chartObj.yScale(yObjs[y].yFunct(d)));
            }

            focus.select(".focus.line").attr("transform", "translate(" + chartObj.xScale(chartObj.xFunct(d)) + ")").attr("y1", minY);
            focus.select(".focus.year").text("Year: " + chartObj.xFormatter(chartObj.xFunct(d)));
        }

    };
    return chartObj;
}
```

```css
.chart-wrapper {
  max-width: 950px;
  min-width: 304px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FAF7F7;
}

.chart-wrapper .inner-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

.chart-wrapper .outer-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.chart-wrapper .inner-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.chart-wrapper text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.chart-wrapper p {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.chart-wrapper .axis path,
.chart-wrapper .axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #1F1F2E;
  stroke-opacity: 0.7;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.chart-wrapper .axis path {
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.chart-wrapper .line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}

.chart-wrapper .legend {
  min-width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
}

.chart-wrapper .legend>div {
  margin: 0px 25px 10px 0px;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.chart-wrapper .legend p {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.chart-wrapper .legend .series-marker {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  border-radius: 35%;
  background-color: crimson;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-bottom: -0.16rem;
}

.chart-wrapper .overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.chart-wrapper .focus circle {
  fill: crimson;
  stroke: crimson;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  fill-opacity: 15%;
}

.chart-wrapper .focus rect {
  fill: lightblue;
  opacity: 0.4;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.chart-wrapper .focus.line {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-dasharray: 2, 5;
  stroke-width: 2;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

@media (max-width:500px) {
  .chart-wrapper .line {
    stroke-width: 3px;
  }
  .chart-wrapper .legend {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="multiline.css">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <!--<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>-->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="chart-wrapper" id="chart-line1"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    d3.csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/asielen/44ffca2877d0132572cb/raw/9c18f31f9ffbb402b070d88efc9a6381d57c0735/multiline_data.csv', function(error, data) {
      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.year = +d.year;
        d.variableA = +d.variableA;
        d.variableB = +d.variableB;
      });

      var chart = makeLineChart(
        data,
        'year', {
          FinTechs: {
            column: 'variableA',
            color:'pink'
          },
          SMEs: {
            column: 'variableB',
            color: 'green'
          },
        }, {
          xAxis: 'Year',
          yAxis: 'Amount'
        }
      );
      chart.bind('#chart-line1');
      chart.render();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: John thanks so much for such a detailed answer! I since managed to change the color but this solution is cleaner and should allow me to update the standard color to a gradient which was my original desire! thank you!

Comment: Hi John! I've just raised another question around this same chart (adding a third data set) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66546292/is-it-possible-to-add-a-third-data-set-to-my-d3-js-line-chart would really appreciate if you had any ideas?